# Background notification

Tags: ios, swift, background

In my application I need update location in background or when screen is locked. When user approaching to some specified location (alert location) app will notify with sound. As they approach app will beep once, next beep twice, next beep three times.

I know how to update location in background, but I have difficulties in sound alerts. I use audio session with `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound`

```
do {
   let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
   audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
   try audioSession.setActive(true)
} catch {
   print("session does not init")
}
/* *** */
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(beepSound)
```

My algorithm like:
When nearest alert location is found, app plays beep sound.

It works in foreground, but under lock screen does not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow notification under the lock screen, and to do so you need to ask the user for permission. Add the following in your  `application` function in `AppDelegate`:

```
let notificationCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
let categories = Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>(arrayLiteral: notificationCategory)
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: categories)
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
```

Comment: I don't use notification like push. I only need background sound. What can I do?

Comment: Since the app is in background, and not active, you still need permission to play sounds.